# Braintree how do I change the subscription lifecycle period?

Tags: node.js, paypal, subscription, braintree

I am new to braintree and I am implementing a braintree payment gateway for my nodeJs app. I have few concerns when it come to application testing.

1. How can I change the period of one billing cycle. Currently its limited to minimum of 1 month. If it is not changeable what is the workaround for testing multiple billing cycle transactions ??

PS: I did refer to this [how-can-i-change-subscription-period-on-braintree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430001/how-can-i-change-subscription-period-on-braintree) but a valid answer can not be found.

My next question is related to the webhooks in Braintree. When a webhook is triggered for successful charge for subscription it returns a Subscription object which a transaction array which includes all the transactions for that subscription. Is there a way to filter out the data for the transaction which the webhook was triggered for ? It says the array is sorted. Does that mean that 0th position of the transaction array is the last transaction made ??

[Braintree Subscription object reference](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/node#transactions)

Since the test environment does not let us change the billing cycle time I have to wait a month to test this. And if there is a better way to do handle this please advice me on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

It’s not possible to create a subscription billing period shorter than a month in sandbox or production. The previous answer linked in your question — creating a subscription with a 1-day trial period — is a good way to test subscription billing transactions.

The array of transactions inside a subscription object is [sorted by creation date with most recent first](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/node#transactions), so the first transaction within a subscription returned in a webhook notification will be the transaction that triggered the webhook.

You can also take a look at our [webhooks testing page](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/webhooks/testing-go-live/node) for examples of how to generate sample webhook notifications.